Traversal with conditions
I am working with a hierarchical dataset traversing through all levels of children and transforming them based on some conditions. Once, I am done with the transformation, I need to store the transformed element in an array of objects for later use.
Following is an example of what I tried. But it is unable to push the transformation that is happening inside else {if (d.req === "y") block.


const data = [
    {
      name: "f1",req: "n",val: 0,
      children: [
        { name: "l1", req: "n", val: 1 },
        { name: "s1", req: "y", val: 2 },
        { name: "q1", req: "y", val: 3,
          children: [{ name: "i1" }, { name: "l1" }]
        }
      ]
    },
    { name: "d1", req: "n", val: 4, children: [{ name: "s1" }] }
  ];
  
  function traverse(data) {
    let container = [];

    data.forEach((d, i) => {
      if (d.req === "n") {
      
        //some external function
        //I want to push the result of external function to a container
        // for example
        
        container.push({ name: d.name, val: d.val * 100 });

        if (d.children) {
          traverse(d.children);

          d.children.forEach((d) => {
            if (d.req === "n") {
              container.push({ name: d.name, val: d.val * 100 });
            }
          });
        }
      } else {
        if (d.req === "y") {
        
          //some external function
          //I want to push the result of external function to a container
          // for example

          container.push({ name: d.name, val: d.val * -100 });

          if (d.children) {
            traverse(d.children);

            d.children.forEach((d) => {
              if (d.req === "y") {
                container.push({ name: d.name, val: d.val * -100 });
              }
            });
          }
        }
      }
    });
    return container;
  }
 console.log( traverse(data));



The desired final result is the following. I can't figure out what is wrong here.
[{
        "name": "f1",
        "val": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "l1",
        "val": 100
    },
    {
        "name": "d1",
        "val": 400
    },
    {
        "name": "s1",
        "val": -200
    },
    {
        "name": "q1",
        "val": -300
    }
]


Your recursive calls to traverse do nothing to capture any data that is going to be processed by the recursive call. Neither is a return value captured, nor is the array passed into the recursive call to be manipulated there. Which are the two typical ways to "share data" in recursion. The other way would be to have all the calls refer to the same outside variable which is cheating and not exactly in the spirit of recursion. But also not done here. I haven't examined exactly what happens in your code but I heavily suspect this is a problem at a glance.

Can you kindly elaborate on  Neither is a return value captured, nor is the array passed into the recursive call to be manipulated there. If I am doing it wrongly, I want to understand it . Can you please provide an example or maybe an URL that shows what you are referring to?

There are more or less three ways for a function to do something with data and then you can observe the data: 1. return someData in the function and myData = myFn() outside. 2. The function accepts some object that it then mutates: myData = []; myFn(myData); 3. the function modifies some external  variable: let external var; function myFn() { externalVar = someData }; myFn();. The code here does none of that with traverse(d.children); - neither captures a return value (1.), nor passes in container into it (2.), nor does traverse operate on a variable external to it (3.)

You could push the results of the recursive calls.


function traverse(data) {
    const 
        container = [],
        regs = { n: 100, y: -100 };
        
    data.forEach((d, i) => {
        if (d.req in regs) container.push({ name: d.name, val: d.val * regs[d.req] });
        container.push(...traverse(d.children || []));
    });
    
    return container;
}

const
    data = [{ name: "f1", req: "n", val: 0, children: [{ name: "l1", req: "n", val: 1 }, { name: "s1", req: "y", val: 2 }, { name: "q1", req: "y", val: 3, children: [{ name: "i1" }, { name: "l1" }] }] }, { name: "d1", req: "n", val: 4, children: [{ name: "s1" }] }];

console.log(traverse(data));
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }



